# Autohotkey - AltGr hotkey behaves differently from LAlt hotkey

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'm trying to map <kbd>LAlt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to Delete and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to Backspace, so i made this script :

```
<!Space::Delete
<^>!Space::Backspace
```

<kbd>LAlt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> gets mapped correctly to Delete, but <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> doesn't work properly : it removes words like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> would do instead of removing one character at a time.

I switched 'Delete' and 'Backspace' and got the same issue : <kbd>LAlt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> works properly but <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> removes words like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> instead of characters.

I'm guessing this might have to do with the fact that <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is actually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RAlt</kbd>, so the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> might be composed with Backspace or Delete at some point ?

Does anybody know what the cause of this could be, and a solution ?

Comment: Try the Send command: **`<^>!Space:: Send {BS}`**

Comment: This worked, thanks !

Comment: You should also do the same with `Delete` remapping doesn't release the modifier keys.

Comment: @user3419297 You should post that as an answer, as it seems to have resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

While @user3419297's answer is essentially correct, it's advisable in modern versions of AHK to use `SendInput` over `Send`.

```
<!Space::
SendInput, {Delete}
return

<^>!Space:: 
SendInput, {Backspace}
return
```

Comment: It's also advisable to put `SendMode Input` at the beginning of your script, it's actually part of the default template when you create a new script `SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.` I don't think mentioning it every time somebody uses the `Send` command is required. You also created a problem by putting it on a new line without `return`

Comment: @Oleg A good point with the `return`. I'm used to avoiding the ugly one liners some people do in AHK but wasn't writing it as a copy/paste solution. In hindsight, this wasn't clear to readers.